# Azure Async Authentication Token from Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asynchronous, adal

I'm trying to retrieve an authentication token from the Azure AD system. I've tried a number of different ways of configuring the async method along with the await command but each time I get the error "A Task was cancelled".

I've got async="true" in my aspx page.

Any ideas what I need to do differently in order to get a successful request and retrieve the token.

The same code works in a console application so therefore, I'm assuming that the issue is something to do with the way the async operations are happening.

My code is as follows:

```
protected async void Login_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    response1.Text = "Started";
    var tentantID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantID"];
    var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationID"];
    var secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secret"];

    await Authorize(tentantID , clientId, secret);
}
private async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetToken(string clientId, string tenantDomain, string clientSecret)
{
    AuthenticationResult result = null;

    var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantDomain);

    try
    {
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        return result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential).ConfigureAwait(false);

    }   
    catch (AdalException ae)
    {
        //Error code
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Error code
        return null;
    }
}

private async Task Authorize(string tenant, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    var authenticationResult = await GetToken(clientId, tenant, clientSecret).ConfigureAwait(false);

    string token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
}
```

EDIT...
My updated code:

```
protected void Login_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    response1.Text = "Started";

    RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(Authorize));
}  
public async Task Authorize()
{

    var tentantID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantID"];
    var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["applicationID"];
    string myKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"];
    var tenantDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantDomain"];

    var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantDomain, false);

    try
    {
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, myKey);
        var result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential).ConfigureAwait(false);

        AuthenticationResult resVal = await result;
        token = resVal.AccessToken;
    }
    catch (AdalException ae)
    {
        //error code
        token = ae.InnerException.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error? If you debug, inside `GetToken()`, do you enter any of those *catches* blocks?

Comment: The AcquireTokenAsync command throws the AdalException with the inner message of "A Task was cancelled"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I have tested this issue by creating my Web Form application target on .NET Framework 4.5 and referencing [Active Directory Authentication Library 3.13.8](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/). Based on your code, it could work as expected on my side and deployed to Azure Web App. Here is my [git sample](https://github.com/brucechen1019/AspDotNet-WebForm-AcquireAADToken/), you could refer to it and try to find out whether it could work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for that. Once I deployed to an Azure Web App it started working, however, the same code locally would not give me the token.

Answer (score 0):

`async void` methods in ASP.NET is not a good thing. See https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx for some info on it.

I believe your `Login_Click` method should use this line to call `Authorize` asynchronously:

```
RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(Authorize(tentantID, clientId, secret)));
```

And then `Login_Click` should just return `void` without the `async` keyword.

Comment: Sadly I'm no further along. I've changed my code as suggested, however, this has not got me any further. I still get the same message as before mentioning "A Task was cancelled" Updated code in edited question.